# Not able to lookup a custom dispatcher

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am using Play 2.3.7 and I need to use Actors from inside the controller. The following code is working fine

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher
val future = (IO(Http) ? Get(url).withHeaders(...).mapTo[HttpResponse]
val result = Await.results(future, Duration.Inf)
```

Now I make the following change to my `conf/application.conf`

```
play {
  akka {
    actor {
      default-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 128
        }
      }
      foo-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 128
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now, change my code to

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup("foo-dispatcher")
val future = (IO(Http) ? Get(url).withHeaders(...).mapTo[HttpResponse]
val result = Await.results(future, Duration.Inf)
```

I get an exception with message `[foo-dispatcher] not configured`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the full path:

```scala
implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup("play.akka.actor.foo-dispatcher")
```

If you want to use `system.dispatchers.lookup("foo-dispatcher")`, define `foo-dispatcher` outside of the `play` namespace:

```scala
play {
  akka {
    actor {
      default-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 128
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

foo-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 128
  }
}
```